# Mobius transformations abelian

Tags: complex-numbers

*Find all the abelian subgroups of the group of Mobius transformations.*

I saw that the dilations and transltions conmute (I did that with fixed points) but that it's like a special case, so I don't have idea how to start to do it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I trust you meant that the dilations commute with each other and the translations commute with each other, not that the dilations commute with the translations.

Comment: Yes, the dilations commute with each other and the translations commute with each other.